# Will my django web app also work on linux?

Tags: django, linux

So I am building a simple crud webapp using django on frontend I am using typescript no frontend frameworks or libraries whatsoever. And currently I am doing this on windows 10 but if I switch to linux Ubuntu completely and continue building this on linux, Will it have any problems when building it even if I use the same version of django and python that was on windows 10.
I am asking this because of problems in past that it works on one machine but not on different so then vm's and container technologies came out.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you will encounter any issues doing so. Most of the developers develop Django applications on Windows machines and deploy them to Linux servers. so you will find plenty of documentation to get it running on Linux.